# I need to register software I own that is no longer supported

Tags: windows-xp, installation, passwords

I have some Cad/Cam software that I have been using for 20 years or so. I need to put in on another computer because the computer it is installed in now is old and having problems. I cannot just put the hard drive with the software into another computer because the software somehow senses that it is in a new computer and requires re-registration. The software is BobCad version 17. I called BobCad and they say they cannot give me the password to re-register the software. The software, when installed, generates a system ID number. This number changes whenever it is installed or when the hard drive with already installed software is moved to a different computer. To register the software you must call BobCad, give them the system ID number, and then they use this number to generate a password for your installation. Even though when I bought the software they said I could re-register it in perpetuity they no longer have the software to generate a new password. I really like this version of their software. I have several newer versions but they are not as near as fast or easy to use for 2D drawings. Is there any way I can somehow fool the software to think it is registered? Even better, is there a way to generate the password? I am not real computer savvy but am willing to try to learn how to get the password.
Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Have you tried using VMWare to virtualize the existing machine?

Comment: We cannot help you circumvent protections built into software, the only people who can help you are the writers of it. There are often "cracks" available but they are legally dubious even for software you are legally entitled to and we cannot recommend or condone using them.